# declaring a type that have no arguments

Tags: types, ocaml, declaration

I have some types :

```
type client =  {nom : nom_client; demande : demande_client}

type itineraire = {num : num_itineraire; 
                   capacite : capacite_itineraire; 
                   liste_clients : client list}

type plan = Vide | Ilist of itineraire list
```

I can declare clients and itineraires because I simply have to specify the arguments. 
However I don't know hoe to declare a variable to be of type plan.

type plan only contains a list of itineraire, but doing :

```
let myPlan = [(an itineraire here)];;
```

Returns an itineraire list instead of a plan.

**So how do I declare a variable of Ilist of itineraire list?**

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `IList` constructor, that takes an `itineraire list` as parameter as indicated in the type declaration, and returns a `plan`.

```
let my_plan = IList [foo; bar; baz]
```

Note that to get the list corresponding to a plan, you also need to pattern-match on this constructor.

```
let merge_plans p1 p2 = match p1, p2 with
  | p, Vide | Vide, p -> p
  | IList l1, IList l2 -> IList (l1 @ l2)
```

PS: do you really need to have this case distinction? Couldn't you defined plans simply as lists, and use the empty list instead of `Vide`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you just left out `Ilist`.

```
let myPlan = Ilist [];
```

Every value of type `plan` has either `Vide` or `Ilist` as its constructor. That's what the definition means.